# Differentiating an integal using change of variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm pretty sure this is a stupid question so apologies in advance.  However I've spent a long time staring at this and can't figure out where I went wrong.

I am asked to show that $h'(t)= \lambda (1-h(t))^2 $.

I am told that the function $h(t)$ satisfies the equation:
$$h(t) = \int^t_0 \lambda e^{-2\lambda s}(1+h(t-s)^2) ds$$

Using change of variables ($u=t-s$), I have rearranged the equation to get:
$$h(t) = \int^t_0 \lambda e^{-2\lambda (t-u)}[1+h(u)^2] du$$
NOTE: $ds = -du$ and changing direction of limits mean signs cancel out.

Then differentiating by $t$ gives:

$$h'(t) = \lambda (1+ h(t)^2)$$ 
which is not the same as what I'm being asked to show.  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you applied Leibniz's integral rule?
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_0^t f(u, t) \, du =
\int\limits_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(u, t) \, du + f(t, t) (t)'-f(t,0)(0)' =
\int\limits_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(u, t) \, du + f(t, t)
$$
With
$$
f(u, t) = \lambda e^{-2\lambda(t-u)}\left[ 1 + h(u)^2 \right]
$$
we get
$$
f_t(u, t) = (-2\lambda)\lambda e^{-2\lambda(t-u)}\left[ 1 + h(u)^2 \right]
= (-2\lambda) f(u,t) \\
f(t,t) = \lambda[1+h(t)^2]
$$
This gives
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} h(t) &=
\frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_0^t f(u, t) \, du \\
&= \int\limits_0^t (-2\lambda)f(u, t) \, du + \lambda[1+h(t)]^2 \\
&= (-2\lambda) h(t) + \lambda[1+h(t)^2] \\
&= \lambda(h(t)^2 -2 h(t) + 1) \\
&= \lambda(h(t)-1)^2 \\
&= \lambda(1-h(t))^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You only differentiated the upper limit; you also need to differentiate inside the integral. This yields the missing contribution $-2\lambda h(t)$.